# Why Google attaches both gclid and gbraid parameters for the same click?

Tags: hyperlink, ads, url-parameters

According to my knowledge, Google would only utilize gbraid or wbraid when they couldn't associate a specific user with a specific click, as with gclid.

After looking through my logs, I discovered that for some queries, Google uses both gclid and gbraid.
I was expecting to see gclid or gbraid separately for different clicks.

Do I have to add gbraid in my offline conversion, or can I just use gclid?

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one parameter and prefer `gclid` when possible. Sending multiple parameters will results in error.

See comments in Google GitHub [code](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/146d7070c1ea2140555d49d73c77892430b37314/examples/remarketing/upload_offline_conversion.py):

```
Args:
    client: An initialized GoogleAdsClient instance.
    customer_id: The client customer ID string.
    conversion_action_id: The ID of the conversion action to upload to.
    **gclid: The Google Click Identifier ID. If set, the wbraid and gbraid
        parameters must be None.**
    conversion_date_time: The the date and time of the conversion (should be
        after the click time). The format is 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+|-hh:mm',
        e.g. '2021-01-01 12:32:45-08:00'.
    conversion_value: The conversion value in the desired currency.
    conversion_custom_variable_id: The ID of the conversion custom
        variable to associate with the upload.
    conversion_custom_variable_value: The str value of the conversion custom
        variable to associate with the upload.
    **gbraid: The GBRAID for the iOS app conversion. If set, the gclid and
        wbraid parameters must be None.
    wbraid: The WBRAID for the iOS app conversion. If set, the gclid and
        gbraid parameters must be None.**
"""
```